# How to convert dvr-ms file in Ubuntu to DVD?

Tags: ubuntu

I have a .dvr-ms file of a recorded TV show from my Vista Media Center.  I would like to burn this to a DVD that can play on any standalone DVD player.  My main PC that I want to use to convert it to a DVD format is running Ubuntu 10.04.

I am able to play the file in Ubuntu using VLC (which surprised me) so I'm assuming I have what I need to decode it.  I guess my questions are:

What format do I need to convert this file to so that I could burn it to a playable DVD?  I started to go through VLC's conversion process and chose I think H264 and AAC or something, and it gave a message about not having an AAC encoder.  I'll look into that some more tonight, but is that something I could then burn to a DVD?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/)